# ffmpeg sync issue when muxing audio and video

Tags: audio, video, merge, ffmpeg, concatenation

I have an issue with ffmpeg. I am not a pro user so I'm on a constant trial & error mode. I would need a little help from this community that helped me countless time before.
I downloaded separate audio and video segments of a video stream. Both audio and video were shown in the Network tab as being .m4s files, but the .m3u8 playlist gave me .ts files for both. So then I downloaded the whole audio batch and concatenated it into a single .ts file. I did the same with video, but using a .mp4 output.

EDIT: When merging the audio .ts files, I encounter this issue:

```
[mpegts @ 0x7f88cb805600] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; 
previous: 1077120, current: 1073280; changing to 1077121. This may 
result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
```

UPDATE: Just noticed that when I examine the .ts audio file with MediaInfo, the frame rate is 41.667 fps (1152 SPF).

So now I have two files: a working single .ts with audio and a working single .mp4 with video.
Only when I tried to merge them, however, I noticed that audio and video resulted as out of sync.
This is because audio has a different length from video (don't know why, they were the same amount of segments: 750). 
Audio info:

```
Input #0, mpegts, from 'output.ts':
Duration: 01:14:12.11, start: 1.400000, bitrate: 434 kb/s
Program 1 
Metadata:
  service_name    : Service01
  service_provider: FFmpeg
Stream #0:0[0x100]: Audio: mp2 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 384 kb/s
```

I can see that for some reason, it starts at 1.4s.

Video info:

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'output.mp4':
Metadata:
major_brand     : isom
minor_version   : 512
compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
encoder         : Lavf58.12.100
Duration: 01:14:57.84, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2425 kb/s
Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 2423 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc (default)
Metadata:
  handler_name    : VideoHandler
```

Video and audio are synced at the beginning (somehow the 1.4 start makes sense) but audio starts drifting and goes out of sync after a while. How do I solve the issue?

Comment: Did you install ffmpeg globally?

Comment: I installed it through Homebrew with the
    $ brew install ffmpeg
command line and all the options included.